# Python Multiprocessing Pool with class instance as argument

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, instance, pool

I would like to run my code in parallel by passing, however I am getting the following error: cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup **builtin**.function failed

Below is the basic code structure. I would like to run the increment_ID's function in parallel. Thanks for helping.

```
class Firm():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = 0

    def print_ID(self):
        print self.ID

class simulations():
    def __init__(self):
        self.firms_list = [firm.Firm() for count in xrange(10)]

    def increment_IDs(self):
        for firm in self.firms_list:
               firm.ID += 1
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Post your _full_ code, including what caused the error, not just the part you think is the problem.

Comment: The full code is quite lengthy. It would really help me if the above demo code can be parallelized

Comment: Well, the code above doesn't work.  What is `firm.Firm` in `__init__`?